# udp client receiving a text file

Tags: c

I am trying to receive a text file over a UDP socket, the client builds fine but gives a blank console, after some experimentation I've found out that the problem lies with the reception, so I am posting that part of my code:

```
size_t data=0;
if(data=recvfrom( sd, file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer), 0
                , (struct sockaddr *) &server, &server_length) < 0)
{
  printf("Error receiving file.");
  exit(1);
}

if(data==sizeof(file_buffer))
{
  printf("Received Data:[%s]",file_buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should re-write you if you forgot to add parenthesis ()

> if( data=recvfrom(sd, file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server,    &server_length)<0 )

**Reason:**
Precedence of `<` is higher then `=` So in your if() first  `<` performed then `=`
and this cause assigns `data` either `0` when data read successfully  and `1` when `recvfrom()` returns `-1` on error.
look @ [C Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

You code is equipment to on successfully read :

```
if(data = 1 < 0)
```

and on  `recvfrom()` fail its like:

```
if(data = -1 < 0)
```

**Mistake**?  Actually you forgot () parenthesis (or if you don't know you shold add.)  like:

> if( (data=recvfrom(sd, file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server,    &server_length)) <0 )

see I added () like:

```
if( (data = recvfrom() ) < 0) 
    ^                  ^  added in your code
```

**Edit**:

**Second error**: "buffer is not `\0` terminated"

The function [recvfrom()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpc2/cpp_recvfrom.html) if successful worked, returns the length, in bytes, of the message or datagram. And if an end-of-file condition is received or the connection is closed, `0` is returned.

the thing to be notice is *it doesn't puts `'\0'` symbol to terminate buffer.* and you are using `'%s'` to print `file_buffer[]`'s content which excepts null terminated string that also cause Undefined Behavior at run time (and you may get unusual symbols on console if not getting segmentation-fault).

You should always read less then one of `sizeof(file_buffer)` and put null `\0` explicitly, if you wants to use your file buffer as string.

I can suggest you do like:

```
no_Of_bytes =recvfrom( 
                sd, 
                file_buffer, 
                sizeof(file_buffer) - 1, 
                0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &server, 
                &server_length
            );
file_buffer[no_Of_bytes] = '\0';
```

Now your `file_buffer` is null terminated you can use with `%s`, but be sure you are not making mistakes in other part of code.

Comment: ok so now I am receiving data on the client side and have been able to write it in a text file as well,but I still have one problem: inspite of the data being written,I get"Error writing file" on the console,and well I get a little bit of redundant data!!!

Comment: @AaymanKhalid Read updated answer. your `file_buffer` is not string and you are using `%s` to print its content. that is one more bug in your code.